# I'm unable to convert a 2d numpy ndarray of dtypes object to dtypes float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

I'm working on this project in which I have a function that outputs data in the form of an array, but I can't seem to convert it to float. I've tried using dtypes and astypes, both didn't work.

```
 def prep_arr(n,index):
    output = []

    if index:
        path_index = index
    else:
        path_index = 0

    while len(output) !=n:
        stock = self.load_stock(self.paths[path_index])
        for i in range(len(stock)//30-1):
            if len(output)==n:
                break

            if stock[30*(i+1)+1][3] > stock[30*(i+1)][3]:
                y = [1,0]
            else:
                y = [0,1]

            output.append([stock[30*i:30*(i+1)],y])
        path_index+=1
    
    return np.array(output)
    
test = prep_arr(10,40)
print(training.dtype)
```

Comment: The code is not reproducible. Please consider editing it to be minimal reproducible code. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by converting an array to float? array is a group of elements while float is single data type.

Comment: Hi I want to convert every element of the array to a float, sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: And what is the element type in your current array? are the elements, array objects themselves? if so, what is their dtype? An example of your array will help us understand better. Thank you

Comment: Could you give us an example output from your function, eg. `print(test)`

Comment: It had too many character so I made a github project with it https://github.com/Thickfork/exemple-array/tree/master

Comment: Code like this that depends on loading some file is useless to us.  We can't test or reproduce your results.  If the problem with converting the `dtype` of `test`, then you need to tell us about that array.  The basics are `shape` and `dtype`. Especially if `dtype` is `object` you need to show us some of the values.  It may be a array of lists or other arrays - which vary in size.

Answer (score 1):

```
# here is a string
output = "23764.234234"
print(type(output))

# make the string a float
float_output = float(output)
print(type(float_output))
```

note the screen cap below for sample :)

[image: cap]

**This was added after the first comment below** :)
*In order to receive a clear answer, one must ask a clear question :)*

```
# Let's create an array
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])

# Let's show our datatype
a.dtype

# Let's convert that datatype to a float
b = a.astype(float)

# and confirm that the conversion took place
b.dtype
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry if my question was unclear but i want to convert every element of the array to a float and I can only use this technique on a 1d array not a 2d like I have here.Thanks for your time anyways!

Answer (score 1):

From your link, your data looks like it is of the form:

```
[array([['22.634', '22.634', '21.127', '21.244', '76012'],
       ['21.244', '21.372', '21.203', '21.303', '72856'],  
       ['21.313', '21.313', '21.169', '21.244', '19960'],  
       ['21.253', '21.295', '21.253', '21.295', '37780'],  
       ['21.338', '21.338', '21.253', '21.33', '10960'],   
       ['21.38', '21.38', '21.137', '21.203', '69382'],    
       ['21.203', '21.203', '21.127', '21.195', '14168'],  
       ['21.195', '21.195', '21.169', '21.186', '6260'],
       ['21.211', '21.211', '21.195', '21.203', '7180'],
       ['21.211', '21.262', '21.211', '21.253', '16723'],
       ['21.279', '21.372', '21.22', '21.279', '26393'],
       ['21.295', '21.372', '21.262', '21.372', '5603'],
       ['21.414', '21.414', '21.354', '21.414', '16722'],
       ['21.414', '21.531', '21.33', '21.531', '15262'],
       ['21.523', '21.523', '21.295', '21.338', '14198'],
       ['21.322', '21.389', '21.288', '21.389', '7128'],
       ['21.389', '21.43', '21.389', '21.422', '1067'],
       ['21.363', '21.438', '21.363', '21.422', '2965'],
       ['21.438', '21.507', '21.354', '21.38', '12356'],
       ['21.405', '21.422', '21.38', '21.38', '6402'],
       ['21.464', '21.507', '21.464', '21.507', '2830'],
       ['21.464', '21.507', '21.43', '21.43', '6772'],
       ['21.539', '21.539', '21.354', '21.422', '11167'],
       ['21.405', '21.464', '21.405', '21.464', '8062'],
       ['21.389', '21.456', '21.363', '21.438', '4988'],
       ['21.464', '21.464', '21.389', '21.464', '7366'],
       ['21.464', '21.464', '21.303', '21.372', '4979'],
       ['21.447', '21.447', '21.447', '21.447', '1417'],
       ['21.447', '21.464', '21.354', '21.456', '15294'],
       ['21.464', '21.548', '21.38', '21.464', '23433']], dtype='<U10')
  list([0, 1])]
```

which I assume isn't what you want. Can I firstly suggest that you convert each array, which contains `int` and `float` to a `float` array as such:

```
a = np.array([['22.634', '22.634', '21.127', '21.244', '76012'],
           ...]).astype(np.float)
```

Secondly the appended list at the end is a different shape to the array so they won't stack. You should think about what this list means and why you want it. But to add it to the array you could do something like:

```
b = [0, 1]
# make new array that will stack
c = np.empty(a.shape[1])
# fill it with NaN values
c.fill(np.nan)
# add in the data from list b
c[:len(b)] = b
c
>>> array([ 0.,  1., nan, nan, nan])
```

Then you can stack `a` and `c` to give you a proper array:

```
np.row_stack([a, c])
>>> array([[2.2634e+01, 2.2634e+01, 2.1127e+01, 2.1244e+01, 7.6012e+04],
   [2.1244e+01, 2.1372e+01, 2.1203e+01, 2.1303e+01, 7.2856e+04],
   [2.1313e+01, 2.1313e+01, 2.1169e+01, 2.1244e+01, 1.9960e+04],
   [2.1253e+01, 2.1295e+01, 2.1253e+01, 2.1295e+01, 3.7780e+04],
   [2.1338e+01, 2.1338e+01, 2.1253e+01, 2.1330e+01, 1.0960e+04],
   [2.1380e+01, 2.1380e+01, 2.1137e+01, 2.1203e+01, 6.9382e+04],
   [2.1203e+01, 2.1203e+01, 2.1127e+01, 2.1195e+01, 1.4168e+04],
   [2.1195e+01, 2.1195e+01, 2.1169e+01, 2.1186e+01, 6.2600e+03],
   [2.1211e+01, 2.1211e+01, 2.1195e+01, 2.1203e+01, 7.1800e+03],
   [2.1211e+01, 2.1262e+01, 2.1211e+01, 2.1253e+01, 1.6723e+04],
   [2.1279e+01, 2.1372e+01, 2.1220e+01, 2.1279e+01, 2.6393e+04],
   [2.1295e+01, 2.1372e+01, 2.1262e+01, 2.1372e+01, 5.6030e+03],
   [2.1414e+01, 2.1414e+01, 2.1354e+01, 2.1414e+01, 1.6722e+04],
   [2.1414e+01, 2.1531e+01, 2.1330e+01, 2.1531e+01, 1.5262e+04],
   [2.1523e+01, 2.1523e+01, 2.1295e+01, 2.1338e+01, 1.4198e+04],
   [2.1322e+01, 2.1389e+01, 2.1288e+01, 2.1389e+01, 7.1280e+03],
   [2.1389e+01, 2.1430e+01, 2.1389e+01, 2.1422e+01, 1.0670e+03],
   [2.1363e+01, 2.1438e+01, 2.1363e+01, 2.1422e+01, 2.9650e+03],
   [2.1438e+01, 2.1507e+01, 2.1354e+01, 2.1380e+01, 1.2356e+04],
   [2.1405e+01, 2.1422e+01, 2.1380e+01, 2.1380e+01, 6.4020e+03],
   [2.1464e+01, 2.1507e+01, 2.1464e+01, 2.1507e+01, 2.8300e+03],
   [2.1464e+01, 2.1507e+01, 2.1430e+01, 2.1430e+01, 6.7720e+03],
   [2.1539e+01, 2.1539e+01, 2.1354e+01, 2.1422e+01, 1.1167e+04],
   [2.1405e+01, 2.1464e+01, 2.1405e+01, 2.1464e+01, 8.0620e+03],
   [2.1389e+01, 2.1456e+01, 2.1363e+01, 2.1438e+01, 4.9880e+03],
   [2.1464e+01, 2.1464e+01, 2.1389e+01, 2.1464e+01, 7.3660e+03],
   [2.1464e+01, 2.1464e+01, 2.1303e+01, 2.1372e+01, 4.9790e+03],
   [2.1447e+01, 2.1447e+01, 2.1447e+01, 2.1447e+01, 1.4170e+03],
   [2.1447e+01, 2.1464e+01, 2.1354e+01, 2.1456e+01, 1.5294e+04],
   [2.1464e+01, 2.1548e+01, 2.1380e+01, 2.1464e+01, 2.3433e+04],
   [0.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00,        nan,        nan,        nan]])
```